# How to search a string in the list of answers added by me on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, search

I am able to view all the answers given by me and questions asked by me, but not able to search a string in them?

Currently I have no other choice than clicking each ques/ans link manually (very hectic) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search a specific string in your questions/answers, use this search string:

[user:me "SQL"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+%22SQL%22)

For search the string only in **answers**:

[user:me "SQL" is:answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+%22SQL%22+is%3Aanswer)

For search the string only in **questions**:

[user:me "SQL" is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+%22SQL%22+is%3Aquestion)

---

Here **SQL** is searchable string.

For more help on advance search tips, refer this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)